# ¿ qué tipo de excepción debo usar para validar un parseInt?

Tags: java

```
do { 
        try { 
            continua = false;
    System.out.println("Ingrese Identificador del Empleado ");
    idEmpleado =  parseInt(miObjeto.nextLine()) ;
        } catch (InputMismatchException nfe) { 
            System.out.println("");
            System.err.println("Se permiten caracteres numericos"); 
            miObjeto.next();
            continua = true;
        }
    } while (continua);
```

/* El error que devuelve el compilador es el siguiente:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
at Main.main(Main.java:32)
*/

Comment: La excepción la estás publicando tú mismo. Arroja un [`java.lang.NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). Te recomiendo leer la documentación de las [Excepciones en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html), sé que al inicio es difícil comprender muy bien la documentación, pero sirve demasiado.

Comment: Hola @Eduardo Jiménez , gracias por contestar, ya había visto la excepción devuelta por el compilador (NumberFormatException), la había integrado al catch,  tampoco me permitía capturar correctamente mi entrada, así que eliminé el uso del parseInt y asunto arreglado., un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

// He cambiado el código como aparece a continuación, ahora funciona correctamente:

```
do { 
        try { 
            continua = false;
    System.out.println("Ingrese Identificador del Empleado ");
    idEmpleado =  (miObjeto.nextInt()) ;
        } catch (InputMismatchException nfe) { 
            System.out.println("");
            System.err.println("Se permiten caracteres numericos"); 
            miObjeto.next();
            continua = true;
        }
    } while (continua);
```